# How to get the index of a selected row in row command in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to get the index of the selected row in my grid view.

This is the command im using on row_command of  my gridview

```cs
if (e.CommandName == "Select")
{
    iCol = gtsk.GetColumnIndexByDBName(grdUser, "UserID");
    if (iCol != -1)
    {
        txtUserName.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(grdUser.Rows[inDx].Cells[iCol].Text.ToString().Trim());
        txtUserName.ToolTip = Server.HtmlDecode(grdUser.Rows[inDx].Cells[iCol].Text.ToString().Trim());
    }

    iCol = gtsk.GetColumnIndexByDBName(grdUser, "UserName");
    if (iCol != -1) 
    {
         txtUserName.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(grdUser.Rows[inDx].Cells[iCol].Text.ToString().Trim()); 
    }

    iCol = gtsk.GetColumnIndexByDBName(grdUser, "FullName");
    if (iCol != -1) 
    {
        txtFullName.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(grdUser.Rows[inDx].Cells[iCol].Text.ToString().Trim()); 
    }

    iCol = gtsk.GetColumnIndexByDBName(grdUser, "RoleCode");
    if (iCol != -1) 
    { 
        ddlRoleUser.SelectedValue = Server.HtmlDecode(grdUser.Rows[inDx].Cells[iCol].Text.ToString().Trim()); 
    }

    //iCol = gtsk.GetColumnIndexByDBName(grdUser, "Status");
    //if (iCol != -1) { chkActive.Checked = ((CheckBox)grdUser.Rows[inDx].Cells[iCol].Controls[0]).Checked; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use get the index of a selected row on row_command like this

```
int iCol = -1;
        int inDx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```